# Multiple line series with multiple y axis in Infragistics graph

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

Is there any provision of having Multiple line series with multiple y axis in Infragistics graph? If yes please guide me with the appropriate link.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to accomplish that using Infragistics WPF controls. From this link: https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/datachart-multiple-axes

```
var DataChart = new XamDataChart();

var xAxis = new CategoryXAxis()
{
    ItemsSource = data,
    Label = "Date"
};
var yAxis1 = new NumericYAxis()
{
    LabelLocation = AxisLabelsLocation.OutsideLeft
};
var yAxis2 = new NumericYAxis()
{
    LabelLocation = AxisLabelsLocation.OutsideRight
};
var series1 = new LineSeries()
{
    XAxis = xAxis,
    YAxis = yAxis2,
    ItemsSource=data,
    ValueMemberPath="Volume"
};
var series2 = new FinancialPriceSeries()
{
    XAxis = xAxis,
    YAxis = yAxis1,
    ItemsSource=data,
    CloseMemberPath="Close",
    OpenMemberPath="Open",
    HighMemberPath="High",
    LowMemberPath="Low"
};

DataChart.Axes.Add(yAxis1);
DataChart.Axes.Add(yAxis2);
DataChart.Axes.Add(xAxis);
DataChart.Series.Add(series1);
DataChart.Series.Add(series2);
```